# TFS 2015 upgrade: Build definition parameters parsing issue

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

We just upgraded to TFS2015 and now most of our builds wont work. The error looks like this:

> Exception Message: The build controller cannot deserialize the process
>   parameters of the build. Make sure the process parameters are
>   compatible with the assemblies on the build machine. Details: Set
>   property 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.Json'
>   threw an exception. (type Exception)
>
> [...]
>
> Exception Message: TF401070: Could not deserialize the JSON string
>   provided. Details:
>       Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got p. Path 'MSBuildArguments', line 1, position 991. (type
>   BuildParameterSerializationException)
>       Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.set_Json(String
>   value)

I get I have to change the MSBuild arguments so they can be parsed, but it won't let me update the Process tab of the build definition (prompts an error and all the fields are all empty) so I can't edit the parameters.

Is there a solution for this problem? Can I edit the MSBuild arguments in some other way?

Comment: What version of TFS did you upgrade from?  What build process template are you using for your builds (is it custom)?  Can you provide a screenshot of your build definition?

Comment: Would you get the same error if you create a new build definition?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found and posted the answer. - We upgraded from TFS2013, I upgraded the build server to TFS2015 too. But I got the same error in another build server with VS2013 and TFS2013.
- I'm using a custom build process template. Tried changing to the default template but didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Reinstalled TFS2013 in another server, re-pointed Visual Studio to that TFS server and then I could get the build parameters.

The error wen I opened the Build Definition process tab cleared all the fields of the build definition. So I basically inserted all the old values one by one until it failed.

The error was a TFS path that I was passing as a MSBuild argument, TFS2015 doesn't like the '$' at the beginning of the path (I guess it automatically thinks it's a TFS variable, didn't happen with 2013) so I changed it for the ASCII code '%24'. Worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In case you install "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools" and use the command "tfpt.exe  builddefinition", make sure to fix the following error message:

1) The way to fix the above error message is to copy the missing dll ("Newtonsoft.Json.dll") to the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools".

a) Make sure to open an elevated command prompt

b) Copy the file "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools"

c) Close the "elevated command prompt" and open a regular e.g "MS VS 2015 Command Prompt"

d) Confirm that the above error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your build machines should match the version of your server.

The next step is to recompile any custom activity assemblies that this build machine uses, if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem - but the exception only occurred when a build process had "MSBuild Arguments" present ("/maxcpucount").  Further investigation led me to discover build process information was missing from the dump files that were created. The solution specified by **user7982840** corrected both problems:

1. Process details missing from the dump files
2. "Set property
   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.Json'
   threw an exception."